# Calling a user defined PHP functions using AJAX in the same file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to process a form in PHP, however I don't want the page to refresh when the submit button is pressed. Instead I want to check if the email and password is correct; then either log the user in or display an error message (login_error in the example).

All of the code snippets below are in the same file, my question is how do I call a php function using AJAX to process the form in the same file?

Form:

```
<!-- Model dialog for login button -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="login" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="login_form" action="index.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>Login</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group" id="login_error">
                            <label for="login-username" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10" style="color: red;">
                                Oops! Your username or password is incorrect, please try again!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="login-username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="login-email" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="login-password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input required type="password" class="form-control" name="login-password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" href = "#register" data-toggle="modal" formnovalidate>Register</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="login_submit" id="login_submit">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>               
        </div>
    </div>
```

PHP I want to call:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["login_submit"])) {
        $email = $_POST["login-email"];
        $password = $_POST["login-password"];

        if (login($email, $password)) {
            die("<script>location.href = 'LoginSystem/cookiecontrol.php?action=set&email=$email'</script>");    // Set the cookie
        } else {
            echo "<script>$('#login_error').show();</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

JQuery:

```
 <script>
        $("#login_error").hide();

        $("#login_submit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({url: '/PHP%20Files/Computing%20Project%20-%20Website/ICTeacher/LoginSystem/wrongpassword.php',
                data: {action: 'index.php'},
                type: 'post',
                success: function (output) {
                    alert(output);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process the php code via an ajax request in the same page is fairly straightforward but you have to ensure that you only return the data you want rather than the entire page which could easily happen.
To do that use `ob_clean` to discard the output buffer to that current point in the script and then ensure you exit after sending the data.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST["login_submit"] ) ) {

        ob_clean();/* discard any output there may have been so far in the document */

        $email = $_POST["login-email"];
        $password = $_POST["login-password"];

        if ( login( $email, $password ) ) {
            die("<script>location.href = 'LoginSystem/cookiecontrol.php?action=set&email=$email'</script>");    // Set the cookie
        } else {
            echo "<script>$('#login_error').show();</script>";
        }


         /* the ajax request should only process to this point */
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the page is still refreshing when I press the submit button. I was previously using e.preventdefault() before; how could I prevent the page from refreshing in your example?

Comment: In my code there was no javascript! By it's very nature - a submit button will submit the form which either reloads the same page or sends the data to another page - so if you want to capture the POSTed data either rely upon the standard method of submission ( as it is ) or change your button type to a simple button and use javascript to send the data via axaj which is what it appears you want to do. I don't use jQuery so can't guide you with those functions - I would suggest that rather than use php to write out the javascript that does the redirection just use the php header function